# Not Able to run the project through Command Prompt

Tags: java

Hi Sorry for Asking on the Same Question..

I am Running my project in Netbeans

```
 String  build_path=getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
command.add(build_path+"i_view32.exe"); command.add(source_p+"/import_pal="+pal_file+"/convert="+ Dest_p+"");
```

This is Working fine in NetBeans but When i am Running the build from command prompt

```
java -jar "D:\Pallete\dist\Pallete.jar"
```

Gives me Following Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at pal.btn_OkActionPerformed(pal.java:214)
        at pal.access$100(pal.java:22)
        at pal$2.actionPerformed(pal.java:85)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

When I click on Ok Button it throws Exception  at line 214

```
public static String  jarpath ;
public static String  buildpath;
    buildpath  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
    jarpath=getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

Comment: Is the code above the one, that throws the NullPointerEx?

Comment: @hellectronic: I Have done the changes, it throws exception when i click on ok button

Comment: @nirajdeshmukh What line has `214` number? May be you should check the result of calling ClassLoader.getResource("")

Comment: Yes It is calling ClassLoader.getResource("")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If line 214 is `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();`, and `getResource("")`
is the actual code, then this is failing. It tries to call `getPath()` on a null object.

Comment: Can you tell me What exactly it should be.

Comment: I thought that `getResource("")` would throw the NPE because of the "". But since the error is in this line, try to checkout what method returns null. Is it `getResource("")` or even `getClassLoader()`? One the returned objects is null and on this a method invocation is applied and this throws the NPE.

Comment: is there any Difference between file:\D:\Interactives\Pallete\dist and  D:\Interactives\Pallete\dist

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it. `file` specifies a protocol. But this is another question.